# QGraphicsItem itemChange function doesn't match with the item's state?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I used the following itemChange function from my own subclass to trigger a signal as:

```
    QVariant WayPointItem::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
    {
        if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange){
            emit selcState(value.toBool());
        }
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }
```

The selcState signal is connected to a slot as:

```
void WaypointLineItem::toggleText(bool value)
{
    if (wp->isSelected()) //wp is the waypointitem which emit the signal selcState()
        text.show();
    else
        text.hide();
}
```

I found that when I select a waypointitem, it did trigger the itemChange function, and the QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange's bool value is also correct.
However, when it comes to the slot, the wp->isSelected() return's a value that is different.
How could this happen, is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The `QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedChange` is called, when the selected state is about to change. This means the new selected state is in the `value` parameter.

You have to react on the `QGraphicsItem::ItemSelectedHasChanged`, where the selected state has already changed.